# Why is Perl commonly used for writing CGI scripts?

Tags: perl, search, performance, cgi

I plan to add a better search feature to my site, so I thought that I would write it in C and use the CGI as a means to access it. But it seems that Perl is the most popular language when it comes to CGI-based stuff. Why is that? Wouldn't it be faster programmed in C or machine code?

What advantages, if any, are there to writing it in a scripting language?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are reasons to choose a scripting language over C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193912/what-are-reasons-to-choose-a-scripting-language-over-c)

Comment: @David: this question seems to be specifically about Perl versus C for CGI scripts.

Comment: The answers are the same though.

Answer (score 18):

Back in the day when CGI was becoming popular, Perl was the easiest language to use. People could pick up "baby Perl" very quickly, and since the program was a text file, they could easily upload it and pass it around. Since Perl started life as a system administration language, lots of servers already had it installed. When it came time to make a CGI script on some hosting service, Perl was most likely already there. Not only that, a Perl script is pretty much the same on any platform, so what you wrote locally most likely worked exactly the same on a different machine.

It was faster to program for "accidental programmers" in the big scheme of things because they had less to learn before they could make a useful program; they could start with nothing and have a Perl program running in an hour, even if they were just cargo-culting it. They didn't have to worry about all the things that come with writing and compiling a C program, then transferring it to another host (which might be a different platform).

Perl got a quick foothold, and you still see the effects of that today. If Perl had to start from scratch today, I don't think it would necessarily win out over anything else. PHP has certainly taken over the low-end, quick-startup crowd (and for most of them, it's probably the right tool at first).

It didn't hurt that Perl had a lot of text processing features, either. Some people talk about CPAN, but that barely existed when Perl started to get noticed for CGI programming.

However, Perl's not as special for CGI programming as it used to be. It still does all of the great things it always has, but now various other languages have caught up in both functionality, availability, and community awareness.

I started programming CGI stuff in 1994, and I still see how amazingly and mind-boggling hard most frameworks make it. I really wish we had [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st/) back then because you never even know about all the stupid things other frameworks make you do. How much better the world would have been if we'd all learned Smalltalk instead. :)

Answer (score 6):

Security, for one thing.  If you write in C, you have to be very careful to make sure all your string handling is correct so you don't introduce buffer overflows, etc.  In any decent scripting language, someone else has already done that for you.  You may be able to have other security holes, but unless there's a bug in the runtime or an extension module, you won't have a buffer overflow.  This benefit is not limited to scripting languages; compiled languages such as Java and C# provide it as well, and it is obtainable (albeit frequently more difficultly) in C++ with `std::string` and C with a good string library.

Securitywise, Perl has another useful feature not seen in many other systems: "taint" mode.  This keeps you from blindly passing user input to other systems as part of a database query, command line, etc.  This is an excellent benefit when writing CGI scripts, as your script will die cleanly before it passes uninspected user input off to the shell for execution.  Taint mode is not perfect, as the untainting process depends on the programmer doing things correctly, but it at least helps catch code paths you missed.

Also, at this point, Perl has been used for a long time for CGI scripting, so there is a large body of libraries, frameworks, etc. already in existence to make writing new scripts easier.  Plus CPAN has code to do just about anything.

Comment: Although these are nice features of Perl, I rarely run into anyone who chose Perl because of them. Indeed, so few people seem to even use taint mode or know what a buffer is (much less what overflowing it would do).

Comment: I wish people would consider it just for those reasons -- yet, I had someone give me a shell script last month and wanted me to expose it as a CGI.  (taint checking?  what's what?)

Comment: You can wrap the shell script with a Perl CGI wrapper though.

Comment: Oh, trust me, I did ... but it's part of a larger project, and they won't take my replacements for their many shell scripts as the 'official' version ... (not all are CGIs ... but there are some that FTP in files and use the input blindly w/out verifying) ... at least they accepted my change that checked to make sure the shell commands completed before proceeding to the next step, and quoted all arguments (but I have no idea how to make sure there aren't quotes already in the arguments in shell, so it's still crap code)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers mentioned already, for basic web applications network transfer speed is a more common bottleneck than language choice.  It is usually easier to write web applications in Perl than C, so a small difference in runtime speed is not worth the extra effort needed to create the application.  C is in fact sometimes used for certain parts of very computation-intensive web applications.

Answer (score 4):

OK, the rest of the answers gave pretty good objective reasons. Just for completeness, here's a subjective evaluation to give it some color:

I wrote:

- CGI software in pure C (for money, professionally). This included creation of the entire CGI library (that was in the days before CGI libraries were available).
- CGI libraries of my own in Perl
- CGI stuff in Perl using CPAN.

Based on those experiences, the pure C one gave the most satisfaction as far as "Look at this cool technical achievement I made" angle. Especially as that was in the days when CGI was brand shiny new and static HTML was the main content everywhere.

The roll-my-own Perl CGI was a lot easier technically than C one due to all the objective reasons listed in other answers.

And the CPAN Perl projects were the only ones that provided fairly decent delivery turnaround time and allowed me to concentrate on building the business logic as opposed to the plumbing.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest advantage of using Perl is [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

Comment: oh, sure, *now* it's all about CPAN -- but back in the day, everyone got their Perl CGIs from Matt's Script Archive.  (which was not a good thing, they later found out).

Answer (score 2):

String manipulation, often a large part of web development, is rather painful and error-prone in C, in parts due to the lack of automatic memory management. Keep in mind that often, script execution time isn't the bottleneck or can be circumvented by proper caching mechanisms. In many cases, it's a good idea to choose a language which maximizes developer productivity instead of unnecessarily sacrificing development time for performance gains which will go unnoticed by the user of the site.

This general principle does not, however, fully apply in your case, as a search engine might well benefit from optimized low-level code. This doesn't mean that you'll have to do everything in C, though: the PHP interpreter has been known to be painfully slow, but as most library functions are implemented in C, you can get away with it. I'd recommend to write the app in the high-level language of your choice, and only re-implement the parts in C which have been identified as botlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the benefit for using a scripting language, is *most* people are much more productive using a higher level dynamic language than they are using C.

A lot of people seem to worry about speed, but in reality it's normally fine...and if it does become an issue most scripting languages have a extension mechanism where you can write modules in C and still use them in the higher level scripting langauge (Like XS in perl, or pythons c-api)

Answer (score -2):

At the time CGI was invented back in the early days of the web, it was the only way do any kind of dynamic processing of web requests, such as responding to forms being submitted or clicking on an imagemap. The web server software itself could deliver only static content, so external programs were needed to handle the interactive stuff.

The first webmasters were probably also system administrators who were often well-versed in Perl. I remember the first NCSA httpd servers came with sample CGI programs written in Perl, C, and shell. The shell scripts were discarded pretty quickly because they were insecure and not good for anything other than really short CGI programs. The C programs worked fine, but Perl was so much more convenient.

My guess is Perl took off as the de facto standard language to use with CGI for several reasons:

- System administrators were familiar with it.
- Fast, secure libraries became widely available; the CGI.pm module is shipped standard with Perl.
- Perl offered a good compromise between speed and ease of development.

There's no reason why Perl has to be used; any language that can work with Unix environment variables is suitable.

That said, CGI has fallen out of favor because it's very slow relative to the languages that run in the web server's address space, such as PHP.

Comment: Your final paragraph is a bit iffy, technically speaking--while I am sure *you* understand that CGI is an interface and **not** a language, your writing makes it easy for others to misinterpret and conflate the two terms. Also, the slowness is latency due to repeated process-startup overhead. The speed issues with CGI have been addressed in two primary fashions: by embedding dynamic language interpreters into the webserver (Apache + mod_php, mod_ruby or mod_perl) and by using CGI accelerators like FastCGI or SpeedyCGI. Also, PHP scripts can be (and are) used with CGI to provide web content.

Comment: PHP is frequently run as CGI on hosting providers