# Do I need to specify object type when creating globals in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
 ...
```

I would like to declare oTable as a global but I am a bit confused. With javascript how do I do this and do I have to specify the object type when I declare it as a global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, you don't. You just declare the variable as you did, and use it wherever you need.

When you'll want to use a global variable in a function, you can simply type its name, without declaring it first.

**Example**

```
var MyVar = $('#dataTable').dataTable(); // This is a global variable. Notice that you don't specify a type, as JavaScript is not strongly typed

function MyFunction() {
  var InternalVar = MyVar; // Here you take the value from the global variable, i.e. the datatable
}

function MyOtherFunction() {
  var MyVar = 'This is a string';

  var InternalVar = MyVar; // Here you take the value from the LOCAL variable, which you declared just above, i.e. 'This is a string'
}
```

Comment: You have declare MyVar as 'Something'. But in my case it's an object (datatable). Do I have to declare it as a string like you did ?

Comment: No, I used a string just as an example. JavaScript is not strongly typed, therefore you can declare a variable as anything you like. I'll update the example using your code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it globally like this without any problem. Var is generic type and any type could be assigned to it.

```
var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({......

function someFunction()
{

}
```

Comment: Wait the first line isn't a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are not actually variables, but properties of the global object. They can be explicitly attached as follows:

```
window.oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({});
```

`window` refers to the global object in browser javascript.

Comment: It's not a string however :-(

Comment: It's anything you want. On assignment time, it'll become an object.

Comment: Do I need to specify window? Can I just use window.otable = null;

Comment: @Anne oh right, the value doesn't matter. I was just too lazy to copy paste your value.. will edit

Comment: Window.oTable is an example. The thing is, there're contexts above functions that work like a global scope. So, if you declare 'var yaddaYadda = $("#yadda").jquerySomething...' OUTSIDE any function or code block, it will be seen by ALL methods in ALL scripts loaded for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that declaration is inside of a function, `oTable` is already a global variable. Also, Javascript is dynamically-typed, which means you're not can't define the variable type.

For more information on global variables in Javascript, check out [this](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable/) article.
For more information on static vs dynamic typed, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/125367/1188942) question.

Comment: But how do I declare it globally?

Comment: @Anne - If you declare it with outside of any functions, then it's a global variable.

Comment: But how can I declare it. Do I need to specify the object type?

Comment: @Anne - No... in fact, you can't specify the object type.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* declare a type.

Unless the variable is defined within a function using `var` it'll be a global.

Comment: But it's used inside a function so how do I declare it globally?

Comment: @Anne By not declaring it with a `var` inside a function.