# Does the implicit type conversion change the size of the variable

Tags: c

for example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int x = 5;
    double y = 6;
    int z = x+y;

    printf("size of z = %d bytes",sizeof(z));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is **4** bytes, why doesn't it converted to double and takes **8** bytes of memory as a double.

Comment: Because it's an `int`. `z` will **not** be cast to `double`.

Comment: also your `printf` format is not correct. It should be `%zu` because the type of `sizeof` is `size_t` and should include a `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read the comments** which describe your code behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

int x = 5;
double y = 6;
int z = x+y; // 5 (int, 4 bytes) + 6 (double, 8 bytes)
             // converting `int` to `double` when adding them ()
             // 5.0 (double, 8 bytes) + 6.0 (double, 8 bytes)
             // 11.0 (double, 8 bytes)
             // But! `z` is of type `int`, so it will not convert to `double`
             // Then 11.0 converts to 11 because `z`... is of type `int`! 
            /// read "Double-precision floating-point format" and you'll see why.
             // So,  z = 11 (`z` is of type `int`, so it's size is *4* bytes )
             // Here is your 4 bytes instead of 8! ;)

printf("size of z = %d bytes",sizeof(z));
return 0;
```

}

Comment: the person who posted the question says "The output is 4 bytes, why doesn't it converted to double and takes 8 bytes of memory as a double".. what are you trying to answer?

Comment: i meant that the questioner is saying that he received the output of 4 bytes... why isnt it 8 bytes.. he wants to understand why the output is 4 bytes... and you are explaining why it is 8 bytes.. read question carefully once more..

Comment: there are two types of type casting: implicit and explicit.. in implicit: the conversion is from higher to lower..and that is whats happening here.. while in explicit the conversion is lower to higher: which the compiler doesnt perform automatically.. so in this program the conversion is automatic=implicit= from double to int..

Comment: @Abhishek, `z = 5 + 6.0` ---> `z = 5.0 + 6.0` ---> `z = 11.0` ---> `z = 11`; `z` is 11 (int) that is of size 4 bytes.

I wonder if I was mistaken... What is wrong?

Comment: this is the breakup: z = 5 + 6.0 ---> z = 5 + 6---> z = 11; z is 11 (int)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35497/discussion-between-yulian-khlevnoy-and-abhishek)

Answer (score 4):

No, `sizeof z` will always be `sizeof(int)`

When you do:

```
int z = x+y;
```

The value of `x` will be converted to `double` since `y` is double, but this won't change `x`. And the result of `x+y`(type `double`) will be converted to `int`, and assigned to `z`.

Comment: you said that x will be converted to double but this won't change x, how??!! @YuHao

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy:  Note **value** of `x`  promoted to `double` **in expression only**, it doesn't means `x` itself covered to `double`, C/C++ are "statically typed language" (in contrast of "dynamic typed language" e.g. Python) that means type of a variable can't be change.  Also try `sizeof(x + y)` you will get == `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy you may like to read: [Dynamic type languages versus static type languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages)

Comment: @YuHao right, when 5 is promoted to double, it will be 5.0, how it will be saved in memory ? for example 5 will be 00000101 . 5.0 will be what?, sorry for being foll

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy Google about the difference between **lvalue** and **rvalue**, that should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined z to be integer. While doing "x+y", the addition does happen on double size but when assigning it performs implicit conversion and truncate the result to fit in size of z.

Answer (score 0):

Since you *declared* z being *int* it' ll be *int*. And every possible conversion will be from whatever type to int:

```
  int z = whatever (legal) formula you put here; 
  sizeof(z); /* <- 4 */
```

on the contrary *temporal* value of x + y is double which is finally converted to int

```
  int x = 5;
  double y = 6;
  int z = x+y; /* x + y = 11.0 since y = 6.0; which is converted to 11*/
```

Comment: when the variable x is promoted to double, does it take 64 bytes instead of 32. and if not how can the compiler handle this implicit conversion ?

Comment: As far as I know, just truncate (throw away fraction part, while preserving integer part)

Answer (score 0):

Your output is `4` because you are declaring `int z`. **`z` will always be of type `int`.**

Even if the expression `x+y` is of type `double` because `y` is a `double`, this expression will be implicitly converted to `int` because you try to assign `int` to and `int`.

Check this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    double y = 5;
    int z = x+y;

    printf( "%d %d \n", sizeof(z), sizeof( x + y ) );
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be `4 8` because **`z` is of type `int`** and the expression `x+y` of type `double`. [Example](http://ideone.com/OKv6Xo)

Comment: how can you say that the expression of x+y of type double, what does it mean ??!!