# Which logic for adding an int and a double is correct?

Tags: c, logic, type-conversion

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int x = 5;
    double y = 6;
    int z = x+y;

    printf("size of z = %d bytes",sizeof(z));
    return 0;
}
```

Which logic correctly describes what happens on the line - `int z = x+y`?

- 5 (int, 4 bytes) + 6 (double, 8 bytes)
- converting `int` to `double` when adding them ()
- 5.0 (double, 8 bytes) + 6.0 (double, 8 bytes)
- 11.0 (double, 8 bytes)
- But! `z` is of type `int`, so it will not convert to `double`
- Then 11.0 converts to 11 because `z`... is of type `int`!
  Read "Double-precision floating-point format" and you'll see why.
- So,  z = 11 (`z` is of type `int`, so it's size is *4* bytes )
- Here is your 4 bytes instead of 8! ;)

or

- 5 (int, 4 bytes) + 6 (double, 8 bytes)
- Converting `double` to `int` when adding them () implicit conversion
- 5 (int, 4 bytes) + 6 (int, 4 bytes)
- 11 (int, 4 bytes)

Comment: Hint: also print out `sizeof(x+y)`.

Comment: This question is awful. Your initial title was useless, although this has been improved slightly. You have two blocks of code which are exactly the same (except for the comments), and you don't really explain what you are asking. I would advise: 1 block of code, then a paragraph explaining your two assumptions of the logic and asking specifically what line `int z = x+y;` is doing

Comment: Isn't this *pretty similar* to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248528/does-the-implicit-type-conversion-change-the-size-of-the-variable asked an hour back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the picture, taken from [www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm), that will substitute my long answer:

**"Compiler first performs integer promotion, if operands still have different types then they are converted to the type that appears highest in the following hierarchy:"**

[image: Usual Arithmetic Conversion]

Answer (score 4):

The first one. It will converted to `double` to perform the calculation and then converted back to `int` to do the assignment.

Comment: Note that the result isn't necessarily 11 however. It depends on whether 11.0 can be represented as a double or not. Suppose it ended up as 10.999999, then the result would be 10 instead.

Comment: @Lundin is this a big problem in the low range? Or was that an example of what might happen at large ranges?

Comment: @KarthikT It has to do with the nature of floating point numbers, something I'm probably not the right person to explain... Classic reading on the topic is David Goldberg's [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(z)` is 4 because `sizeof(int)` is 4 - Doesn't matter what you try to assign to `z`. That's a totally separate issue from how the type conversions are done.