# Trying to use subclass method but it is not letting me

Tags: java, inheritance

So say I have 3 classes, Tester, Fruit (superclass), and Apple (subclass)

I have written a new method in Apple (which extends Fruit). The method being:

```
public String getAppleColor()
```

Now say in Tester I have created an array of 10 Fruit

```
Fruit fruitArray = new Fruit[10]
```

and say I make one of them

```
fruitArray[3] = new Apple()
```

This is fine, since Apple is also of type Fruit. However I wish to use my getAppleColor() on this specific element of the array:

```
String appleColor = fruitArray[3].getAppleColor();
```

How come this is not working? When I look at useable methods on fruitArray[3] in eclipse, none of my Apple methods show up, but I made fruitArray[3] an Apple?

Comment: It's because Java is a statically typed language. You may be used to dynamically typed languages like most scripting languages. You can only invoke methods that are known at compile time to be part of the type. You can use a cast expression to override the static type of a variable. (For a *solution* to your problem, see the answers below) For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages

Comment: If you already know that `fruitArray[3]` is an apple, don't you also already know the color? In other words, why does it make sense to assume `fruitArray[3]` is an apple, but it doesn't make sense to replace the call to `fruitArray[3].getAppleColor()` with `"Red"` or `"Green"` or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `getAppleColor()` on `Fruit` reference, it doesn't declare that method

better design would be have `getFruitColor()` defined and make `Fruit` abstract class / make it interface and force each `Fruit` implement this method

Compiler doesn't know what implementation it is going to be assigned at runtime

Comment: Thanks. Just for confirmation, if I create an object (Fruit object in this case) and want to use a subclass method, it is mandatory that I have that method implemented in the superclass too (Fruit)?

Comment: No declaration is fine, please refer to polymorphism in java

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast it to an `Apple` since the compiler won't know that `fruitArray[3]` will contain an Apple (it might contain any other sort of `Fruit`). Try:

```
String appleColor = ((Apple)fruitArray[3]).getAppleColor();
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot know that at runtime, an element declared as a `Fruit` is actually an `Apple`. As such, it won't let you call any methods declared in `Apple`.

Your array is

```
Fruit[] fruitArray;
```

The compiler can only know that the elements in the array are `Fruit` instances, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better declare a method `getColor()` in class `Fruit`, override it in subclass `Apple`, then you can get color of apple by `fruitArray[3].getColor()`.

Comment: I just confused with the basic concept of "override" and "overwrite".Thanks,DaoWen.