# Auto type vectors

Tags: c++11

I just read about vectors in C++. They seem to be like lists in Python, but they can only take values of the datatype specified in the declaration. For example:

```
vector<int> intlist;
```

Takes only `int` type data. Whereas a list in Python take any type of data. I tried to implement the same in C++ by writing:

```
vector<auto> list;
```

But it resulted in an erroneous compilation. I am not sure why this happens as it works fine with other datatypes.

Comment: `auto` is not a type

Comment: `auto list = std::make_tuple(1, 'c', "foo");`

Comment: Anything in Python can take any type of data. C++ doesn't work this way. See dynamic vs static type system [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way.

C++ is strong typed. `auto` is a keyword used when the type of variable can be determined at compile time, that's not what you want.

If you need to have a vector of object of different types, you must use some library like `boost::any`.

EDIT:

C++ is statically typed and Python dinamically typed, this is the difference. Thanks to @Angew for correcting my mistake.

Comment: +1, but Python is strongly typed as well. The real difference is that Python is dynamically typed, while C++ is statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` is not a variant type, it is simply a shortcut you can use in your code when the type can be deduced by the compiler.

Underneath a Python list is some implementation of a variant and I would suggest using `boost::python` to manage C++ - Python interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if this is something you really want to achieve in c++ I recommend switching to `c++17` and using `std::variant`. This is an example of using `std::variant` which at face-value may seem somewhat similar to a python array.

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using my_variant = std::variant<std::string, float, int, bool>;
int main(){
    std::vector<my_variant> list = {"hello", 5.0, 10.0, "bye", false};
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
         std::visit([](auto arg){std::cout<<arg<<std::endl;}, list.at(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```