# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in rock paper scissors

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" and i don't know why, since everythin seems pretty right ! Could you help me ?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Choose: rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if(computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice === "rock";
} 

else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66){
    computerChoice === "paper";
} 

else (computerChoice >= 0.67 && computerChoice <= 1){
    computerChoice === "scissors";
}
```

Comment: You need to put all that into a function

Comment: You're missing an `if` after the last `else`.

Comment: Thanks @HoboSapiens it worked ! Why can't just do the else of the last if ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else block has a condition. That doesn't make sense. An else block is supposed to catch all other situations, so there's no need for a condition. That's why it expects an opening brace.

Either eliminate the condition or convert it to an else if block.

```
else {
    computerChoice === "scissors";
}
```

Or

```
 else if (computerChoice >= 0.67 && computerChoice <= 1){
    computerChoice === "scissors";
}
```

Also, you should use `=` for assignment. `===` is a [comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

```
computerChoice = "scissors";
```

Also, `computerChoice` is first assigned a number, then later a string. That's risky. JavaScript allows it because it's a [dynamic language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages), but it might be better to use different variables to avoid confusion. So finally, we have:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Choose: rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = "not selected";    
var rand = Math.random();

if(rand >= 0 && rand<= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
} 

else if (rand >= 0.34 && rand <= 0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";
} 

else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you made it very much easier with all that explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is syntax error.
*else* run whenever all evaluation is falsey. So else does not accept condition. 
If you want the program to evaluate more condition use *else if*

```
if(computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice === "rock";
} 

else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66){
    computerChoice === "paper";
} 

else (){
    computerChoice === "scissors";
}
```