# Instantiate an object in switch statement but cant use it outside of the scope of switch statement

Tags: c#

I have 1 PDF "Window Sticker" template class that I can use for all car dealers but this one dealer wants to customize it his way, not the all dealers' way.

So, I created a 2nd PDF "Window Sticker" template class for that particular dealer.

Then I found I'm having trouble instantiating it in switch statement for any particular dealer due to scope issues.  What's the workaround to it, or other way to do it?

```
public class Foo1
{
    public Foo1() { }
    public string GeneratePdf() { return "Red"; }
}
public class Foo2
{
    public Foo2() { }
    public string GeneratePdf() { return "Blue"; }
}

Object pdfTemplate;
long dealerAccountId = 121;  //247

switch(dealerAccountId)
{
   case 247:
       pdfTemplate = new Foo2();
       break;
   default:
       pdfTemplate = new Foo1();
       break;
}

string color = pdfTemplate.GeneratePdf();
```

Comment: Create an `IFoo` interface that has `GeneratedPdf()` in it's contract. Have both classes implement that interface. Then do `IFoo pdfTemplate;`.

Comment: Another option is to just declare `pdfTemplate` as `dynamic`.

Comment: @DavidG: no no no. Do not suggest that option. Just don't. See the comment chain on Patrick's answer.

Comment: @siride Yes, I've already read that and I think you're being a little melodramatic about it all (though you are correct)

Comment: @DavidG: I take it very seriously. There are some things that programmers may be tempted to do because they don't know better, but which end up creating much larger problems. I do not want this site to be a place where bad and dangerous advice is promulgated to beginner programmers.

Comment: Why am I getting a -1 here?  Is my question not valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem isn't the scope. It is the type of your `pdfTemplate` variable. `Object` isn't going to cut it. You should create an [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) that has the `GeneratePdf` method and use that as type. Else it doesn't know the possible methods of the `pdfTemplate` variable, like `GeneratePdf`.

```
public interface IGenerator
{
    string GeneratePdf();
}

public class Foo1 : IGenerator
{
    public Foo1() { }
    public string GeneratePdf() { return "Red"; }
}
public class Foo2 : IGenerator
{
    public Foo2() { }
    public string GeneratePdf() { return "Blue"; }
}

IGenerator pdfTemplate;
long dealerAccountId = 121;  //247

switch(dealerAccountId)
{
   case 247:
       pdfTemplate = new Foo2();
       break;
   default:
       pdfTemplate = new Foo1();
       break;
}

string color = pdfTemplate.GeneratePdf();
```

---

For the OP to understand his options with `dynamic`, please don't use this.

When using `dynamic`, it will try to resolve the method you call on run-time. The compiler doesn't warn you about a non-existing method, it will just assume it is there on run-time (in other words: bugs are only visible after compiling, and possibly after releasing the product). You don't need an interface though.

```
dynamic pdfTemplate;

...

string color = pdfTemplate.GeneratePdf();
```

This will just work, no hassle, just working code. (Check what happens if you make a typo, like `generatepdf()`)

Comment: Using `dynamic` would solve the problem without adding an interface (unfortunately, without type safety as well).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was trying to avoid that subject... :)

Comment: @siride Because OP may not own his `Foo1` and `Foo2` classes.

Comment: That would be the only valid argument in my opinion @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: then OP can wrap them in classes he does own. There are all sorts of type-safe ways to solve this problem. `dynamic` exists to support interop and dynamically-typed languages, and the odd case where you have truly dynamically-constructed and managed objects. It does not exist to lazily circumvent the type system. It's very irresponsible to suggest it here, TBH.

Comment: I can do with Interface and it works great now!  Problem I have is not understanding what Interface is really use for and everyone have different answer.    By the way, what are the example of dynamic one of you were saying so I can see what it looks like.   I'm sticking to Interface.

Comment: @fletchsod: an interface is like a class except that it only describes what methods and properties classes that implement it may have; it does not have any implementation (working code) of its own. Read about them here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson13. Do *not* even think about `dynamic` until you've been programming C# for at least 5 years. Just put it out of your mind.

Comment: Downvoted until you remove the `dynamic` stuff. OP is not well-versed enough in C# or OOP to use `dynamic` responsibly.

Comment: @siride Until (s)he's been programming in C# for 5 years, are you serious? How can you possibly make such a blanket statement?

Comment: Indeed. Downvoting a helpful post that clearly states the *do not use* is a little harsh imho.

Comment: @DavidG: it was a bit of a stretch, but the point is that if the OP doesn't even know about interfaces, then the OP is not going to be able to responsibly use `dynamic`. The OP should learn OOP principles and how they work in C# *first*.

Comment: I have been programming C# for 14 years now.  The thing is the developement team we have aren't using struct, interface, abstract, etc. that much.  Sad, yep, I know.

Comment: @fletchsod: then this is a good time to learn about those things. And don't bother with `dynamic`. You could program the rest of your life in C# without needing to use it.

Comment: @siride unless you code Office add-ins for example. I agree with you though, I barely use it. Only if I have to.

Comment: I was just about to mention Office interop, good luck using that without dynamic :)

Comment: @siride Wrapping would double the number of classes. `dynamic` may have been added to support interop and dynamically-typed languages, but its virtues go far beyond this narrow area of application. I also think that [static type checking tends to be overrated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/125367/335858) to a degree. Anyway, this gets too chatty, so I'm flagging the conversation for deletion by moderators.

Comment: No, just closed it instead of deleting it.  I need to save this accepted answer example.

Comment: @fletchsod Don't worry, it's only the comments that will get deleted. The question and answers will stay.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `pdfTemplate` is of type `object` and type `object` has no method `GeneratePdf()`. Even though the object you assign to the variable is one of the `Foo1`/`Foo2` types, the type of the variable itself is `object`. This is important.

The variable needs to be a type that has a `GeneratePdf()` method. It looks like both of your Foo classes have at least this method. That means they can either inherit from the same base class, or they can implement the same interface. I recommend the latter. So you'd have this:

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    string GeneratePdf();
}

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public Foo1() { }
    public string GeneratePdf() { return "Red"; }
}
public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public Foo2() { }
    public string GeneratePdf() { return "Blue"; }
}

IFoo pdfTemplate;
long dealerAccountId = 121;  //247

switch(dealerAccountId)
{
   case 247:
       pdfTemplate = new Foo2();
       break;
   default:
       pdfTemplate = new Foo1();
       break;
}

string color = pdfTemplate.GeneratePdf();
```

Comment: @musefan: I started writing this answer well before Patrick's appeared. It takes time to write an answer and apparently I am not fast enough. However, I feel like it explains the problem better, so I am leaving it up anyway.

Comment: Can you add some language about why adding `dynamic` is so bad? It's taking up many of the comments which people don't read, but they may read your answer.

Comment: @durron597: I didn't mention it at all in my answer, so I see no reason to say anything about it.

Comment: I just thought it should be included in your answer so that future readers will see it without it being buried in a comment chain, that's all.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    public abstract string GeneratePdf();
}

public class Foo1 : FooBase
{
    public Foo1() { }
    public override string GeneratePdf() { return "Red"; }
}

public class Foo2 : FooBase
{
    public Foo2() { }
    public override string GeneratePdf() { return "Blue"; }
}
```

Also, change this line:

```
Object pdfTemplate
```

Into this:

```
FooBase pdfTemplate;
```

The rest of your code is OK.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem at all.