# How does Java check if an assigned value is correct (in regard to the type)?

Tags: java

In Java you have to specify of which type a variable has to be.

It then makes sure that one can't assign values of a different type to the variable.
Trying to assign a different value results in an error: "*String can not be converted to int.*" for example.

How does the checking work?

Where are the information about the variable-type stored?

In a weakly typed language like JavaScript assigning a string to a current number **wouldn't** result in an error.

How does it work there?

As far as I know determines the type the way values are stored in memory?
Consequently: How can a variable change it's in weakly typed languages? The way of storage wouldn't match anymore.

Comment: Maybe Google more? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html

Comment: @Kayaman: Neither a variable *nor* an object can change its type in Java - but those are separate things.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, that was a bit poorly phrased.

Comment: I think the checkings would be if the word is double quoted it is a String, if its not and its a number, that would be an Integer and so on.

Comment: The information about the type is stored in the Java compiler's symbol table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java goes through a process of compilation. During this process, the compiler verifies that the type of the variable is consistent.
Javascript is not a compiled language. There's no pre-runtime process to verify the type of the variable. More over, javascript is a dynamically typed language, so by design you don't have to worry about the type of the variable.
You can read more about it here:
[Dynamic type languages versus static type languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages)

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides to this - compile-time and runtime checks.

When your code is compiled, it can be checked for any obviously incorrect assignments. The compiler has access to the source and all of the information about the type you have declared for each variable, so this is fairly straightforward.

There are other cases which need to be checked at runtime, such as when you attempt to cast a variable to a different type. Basically, the Java runtime stores some header/metadata along with each object, which includes information about its class. The specific content and structure of this metadata can vary between different versions of Java. But in any case, this information can be checked, and a ClassCastException will be thrown if the cast you are attempting to make is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strictly typed language where we need to decide the type of variable, it may be int, float or an reference type (like Object, String, other class) it is to keep implementation easy and understandable. However Java provides concept of type casting due to which we can convert a variable to another eligible type and there also wrappers present to do so like parseInt(). e.g.

```
Object o = "Something";
String s = (String) o;
```

Because of its strict type nature Java compiler doesn't allow us assign a value to a variable with different type.

Every Java object stores a `klass` named flag to refer to its the Class level object.