# Why does C++ regards as Static Languages

Tags: c++, static, programming-languages

From my recitation class -

> In [free variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) (in function activation):
>
> - Static scoping: free variables are evaluated in the context of the defining occurrence of the function . include many you know: ML, Java,
>     C++.
> - Dynamic scoping: free variables in the function body are evaluated in the context of the function call
> - Static languages:  Common 
>     Include many you know: ML, Java, C++ Advantages  modularity   easier
>     variable access by the compiler

Can you give an example which describes why does C++ regards as **Static languages** ?

Comment: If you mean static-typed languages by static languages: Well, maybe because the ___types are determined at compile time___, e.g. `int an_integer; char a_character;`. For comparison:  `var am_i_an_int = {}; am_i_an_int = "string"; am_i_an_int = 1;` is first an `object`, then a string, and then a number in JavaScript.

Comment: i guess you want to know why C++ is static "typed" language, if so it got nothing to do with scoping, i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583507/moving-from-static-language-to-dynamic might help you... to have basic idea...

Answer (score 2):

static language mean “statically typed language” . for example type of a variable can't be change and defined statically at compilation time.
<sub>But not because of any of reason you mentioned</sub>

```
int i = 10;
```

`i` in int can be char.

in opposite Python for example:

```
>>> x = "yourname"      # x is pointing string 
>>> x = 5               # x pointing number
```

So Python is an example of “dynamic typed language”

Answer (score 0):

A programming language is said to use static typing when type checking is performed during compile-time as opposed to run-time. `In C++, variables need to be defined before they are used so that compilers know what type they are, and hence is statically typed`.

Please take a look at below articles

http://www.jvoegele.com/software/langcomp.html
http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/dynamic-languages-are-static-languages/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B