# Do you prefer compiled or scripted languages?

Tags: scripting, compilation, principles

Since this is wide community using all kind of different technologies, it seems like appropriate place to ask this.

Do you like to compile or do you prefer scripting?

I ask this because I tend to program things in small scripting languages with chosen modules I actually need (like Lua, Awk, AutoHotKey ... ) instead of mainstream languages with full blown non-portable IDEs and big one-size-fits-all libraries where every little change require to load and recompile the project.

I like the ability that the only tool I actually need to change/fix/update the project is any editor available on any system I happen to run the script (and of course, the interpreter which is single executable that I can either carry with me or download it instantly from Internet and just save it on disk without any kind of installation procedure).

I also feel good to know that anybody wanting to update the project doesn't require anything else but the editor - no notorious compilation issues, dependency problems etc., and that anybody that doesn't like the button I put *there*, can open the file and put it wherever he wants or even delete it in a matter of minutes.

I ask this because I noticed that there are some programmers that tend to think that anything that isn't native executable isn't good enough. I even remember one post on the forum where I keep one of my open source applications - another programmer said "*Good app, but it isn't .exe*"

Comment: If you are asking a poll-like question, the question should be asked as a community wiki question.  Otherwise, it will very quickly be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that is the practice.
Maybe bunch of other "subjectional" topics have to do with it, which aren't closed.

Everythign is subjectional. Its wrong that topic is closed. The point was to give people insight about pros and cons of most important choice they need to take.

Answer (score 4):

If i had my wish, i could program and test without compiling and then compile when i was done.

But if i had to choose, i would choose a compiler.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of any tehcnology that allows me to find bugs as early as possible in the development cycle.  As such I tend to be more of a fan of projects that compile vs. are interpreted.  Static compilation is a tool you can use to force error detection into your code at a very early stage.

Answer (score 1):

Without compile time, when would you have time for Stack Overflow (or wheely chair hockey)?

Answer (score 0):

I like to compile. This process gives me information about what is wrong in my syntax, type mismatches and so on. Also compiling makes most files unredable which is great for creating software that isn't opensource. Last but not least compiling makes programs run faster.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that what you are saying is universally true.  Take PHP for example.  It's a scripting langauge.  But there' hundreds of different modules for it.  Something that may work on your computer may not work on another computer.  Also, there's still configuration files (php.ini) and changing the configuration can affect if your program runs the same on different computers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I already said that I would like to choose modules I like to use for a project and mentiond some languages that follow that phylosophy :)