# What is Dynamic Code Evaluation as mentioned by John Resig

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, eval

In his book "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja", John Resig writes:

> Although dynamic code evaluation has been maligned due to its complexity and potential for security issues, without it we wouldn’t have had the CoffeeScript programming language.

I was hoping that someone could explain what is Dynamic Code Evaluation?  Also, are there any code examples (or word examples) that would help better explain it?  Furthermore, are there any website examples that use dynamic code evaluation?

Also, if possible, how did dynamic code evaluation bring about the CoffeeScript programming language?

Comment: "Dynamic code evaluation" in Javascript is basically just "eval".  Here's a good link on why "eval" *ISN'T* necessarily "Evil": http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/  IMHO...

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934/what-do-people-find-so-appealing-about-dynamic-languages

Comment: possible duplicat of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/157698/what-is-meant-by-dynamic-code-evaluation

Comment: Aron, that duplicate is not from stackoverflow.com and also, it is an unclear answer.

Comment: You can use [`<script type="text/coffeescript">`](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts) elements and compile the CoffeeScript to JavaScript in the browser and then `eval` it to make the browser aware of the JavaScript version. This sort of thing is silly in a real application though, in real life you do the conversion server-side using node.js. coffeescript.org's "TRY COFFEESCRIPT" button and jsfiddle.net's CoffeeScript support do the "compile and `eval` in the browser" thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic code evaluation techniques in JavaScript:

- [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function
- [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object, created with the `Function` constructor

Basically you take a string (for example, concatenate it from parts) which contains JavaScript code, and use one of these techniques to parse and run it. The CoffeeScript compiler is actually a [transpiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler): it takes source code written in CoffeeScript (that is, a string), and translates it into JavaScript source code (another string), which is run using `eval`.